# ActiveRecord Query: Create an instance method using scope chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having difficulty creating a class method through an ActiveRecord query:

I have created a class method called popular_users to sort users by their number of followers, but it is not returning any results. The problem lies with `friend_id: self` I believe. If I test in the rails console using `friend_id: User.first` it works. (friend_id is the id of the person being followed)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # received friend (ie a follower): other user sends a request which has been accepted by current user
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :received_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "friend_id"
  has_many :received_friends, -> { where(friendships: { accepted: true}) }, through: :received_friendships, source: :user

  def self.popular_users
    self.joins(:friendships)
        .where(friendships: {accepted: true, friend_id: self})
        .group("users.id")
        .select("users.id, count(friendships) AS followers_count")
        .order("followers_count DESC")
  end
```

I have tried the below method but it results in this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error
>   at or near "SELECT"

```
  def self.popular_users
    self.joins(:friendships)
        .group("users.id")
        .select("SELECT COUNT(friend_id) FROM friendships WHERE (user_id = :user_id AND accepted = 't')) AS followers_count")
        .order("followers_count DESC")
  end
```

**Schema:**

```
  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "friend_id"
    t.boolean "accepted", default: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "name"
  end
```

**UPDATE: This is my answer**

```
  def self.popular_users
    self.joins("RIGHT JOIN friendships ON friendships.friend_id = users.id AND friendships.accepted = 't'")
        .group("users.id")
        .select("users.id, count(users.id) AS followers_count")
        .order("followers_count DESC")
  end
```

Eg testing in rails console:

```
Friendship.create(user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, accepted: true)
Friendship.create(user_id: 4, friend_id: 2, accepted: true)
Friendship.create(user_id: 5, friend_id: 2, accepted: true)
Friendship.create(user_id: 1, friend_id: 3, accepted: true)
Friendship.create(user_id: 2, friend_id: 3, accepted: true)
```

Result returned after typing `User.popular_users` in console is `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 2, followers_count: 3>, #<User id: 3, followers_count: 2>]>`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `.where( friendships: { friend_id: self })`?  I looks like you are asking for only users that have a friendship with a certain (current?) user.

Comment: I'm trying to sum the number of followers each user has (eg, if user has an accepted friendship sent from another user, follower count = 1) and then sort the users in order of descending follower count. (like a popularity list/scoreboard)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

`self` in the context of a class method will be the class object itself.

```
class Test
  def self.test
    self
  end

  def test
    self
  end
end

Test.test
#=> Test

Test.new.test 
#=> #<Test:0x0000010f624bb0>
```

You'll need to pass the desired id into your class method, something like:

```
User.popular_users_for(friend_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that two different users can only have one friendship, try the following:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # . . .

  def self.popular_users
    self.joins(:friendships)
      .where( friendships: { accepted: true } )
      .group("users.id")
      .select("users.id, COUNT(users.id) AS followers_count")
      .order("COUNT(users.id) DESC")
  end

  # . . .
end
```

The `join` from `users` to `friendships` will pull all rows from `friendships` for every user (and the `where` limits the join result to only the accepted friendships you wanted from your original).  For this reason it is sufficient to `COUNT(users.id)` - this will count the total number of rows (friendships) appearing in the join for each user.

Also, most SQL variants don't allow you to name an alias like you did for `followers_count` and then use that alias in the `ORDER BY` clause, so I wrote my answer more generically in case this may also have been part of your problem.

Comment: Hi DRSE, thanks for the explanation. Your class method above returns the total number of users a user is being followed and following, because two diff users can have max 2 friendships (they could either be in the friend_id or user_id column of the friendships.id row). i managed to fix it by using a right join on friendships. my updated class method is above.